# Gradle no detecta mi agconnect-services.json para un flavor

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy construyendo un ejemplo de flavors con el Huawei Push Kit, pero al momento de sincronizar el proyecto con gradle, no detecta mi archivo agconnect-services.json para mi flavor QA, los otros 2 funcionan sin problema.

Como puedo hacer para que detecte el agconnect-services.json en el flavor QA?

Esta es mi configuracion en mi build.gradle:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors{
        qaAT{
            applicationId="com.hms.demo.flavourdemo.qaAT"
        }
        QA{
            applicationId="com.hms.demo.flavourdemo.QA"
        }
        qaAZ{
            applicationId="com.hms.demo.flavourdemo.qaAZ"
        }
    }
```

Y este es mi build output:

```
> Configure project :app
--W- The variant: QADebug, There's no json file
--W- The variant: qaATDebug, Use the json file: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\FlavourDemo\app\src\qaAT\agconnect-services.json
--W- The variant: qaAZDebug, Use the json file: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\FlavourDemo\app\src\qaAZ\agconnect-services.json
--W- The variant: QARelease, There's no json file
--W- The variant: qaATRelease, Use the json file: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\FlavourDemo\app\src\qaAT\agconnect-services.json
--W- The variant: qaAZRelease, Use the json file: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\FlavourDemo\app\src\qaAZ\agconnect-services.json
KotlinDslScriptsParameter(correlationId=30332901644900, scriptFiles=[]) => StandardKotlinDslScriptsModel(scripts=[], commonModel=CommonKotlinDslScriptModel(classPath=[], sourcePath=[], implicitImports=[]), dehydratedScriptModels={}) - took 0.0 secs
```

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

Answer (score 0):

de acuerdo a la configuración de tus flavors

```
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors{
        qaAT{
            applicationId="com.hms.demo.flavourdemo.qaAT"
        }
        QA{
            applicationId="com.hms.demo.flavourdemo.QA"
        }
        qaAZ{
            applicationId="com.hms.demo.flavourdemo.qaAZ"
        }
    }
```

Los archivos `agconnect-services.json` deberían encontrarse en los directorios

`app/src/qaATag/connect-services.json` , `app/src/QA/connect-services.json` y    `app/src/qaAZ/connect-services.json`

Comment: Gracias, si los puse asi, pero solo me detecta los de qaAT y qaAZ